# Add a triangle bend to a drop shadow to div

Tags: html, css, footer, dropshadow

So, I have this site I am redeveloping for a client and it was made like 10 years ago. Currently their entire footer banner is an image. I am trying to preserve the footer to look exactly like the image without having to rely on using an image for the entire content which seems redundant to me because this can be done with HTML and CSS. So I am trying style it exact but cant seem to figure this slight triangular bend effect. I want to add a drop shadow effect to the top border of my footer only with a slight triangle bend effect on top of the logo for the site like this: [image: Desired effect]

I can add the drop shadow straight across no problem, but I am not sure how to add that slight triangle effect like in the image. I am using bootstrap for responsiveness, so have dug around their docs to see if they had any helper classes to help me achieve this. I am not the greatest css expert so i have no idea how to achieve this effect. Is there a way using purely css? javascript or jquery will work too if needed.

This is the basic layout(3 column) of my markup and styles:

```
<div class="row drop-shadow">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
     //content not added yet
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
     //content not added yet
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
     //content not added yet
    </div>

</div>


.drop-shadow{box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)}
```

Comment: You forgot to add the relevant HTML and CSS you're working with. Please take a read of the "*[MCVE]*" guidelines as to why we need to see that.

Comment: Edited post to include it, thanks!

Comment: Wish I had time to do more than comment, but SVG is made for this sort of thing. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a quick possibility here, but [this code](http://codepen.io/beepye/pen/KMdoxQ) creates a simple triangle. You could use it to position the triangle absolute to the element w/ the `box-shadow`. This is the fastest solution I could come up with.

I edited the answer since you've added the CSS & HTML.

Comment: I was able to achieve what i needed by modifying your code just a tad bit on the number of pixels for the left and right and changing the color of the triangle to white. Thank you!

Comment: No worries brotato chip! I just updated for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

To pinch the shadow like that is not something you can do with css. The only way to make it appear like that is to use an image as the original site did. You could crop it to just the shadow and code the rest of the footer as desired.

Answer (score -2):

create a rectangle, **skew** and rotate it then position it properly to get the desired effect.